# Spring Boot Issue while Running the Spring Boot APP

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to run my spring boot app.This time i got error as shown below :

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[32m :: Spring Boot :: [39m      [2m (v1.3.3.RELEASE)[0;39m

[2m2016-04-13 19:56:36.427[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.SampleApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting SampleApplication on kasi-PC with PID 4756 (E:\WS\Sample\target\classes started by kasi in E:\WS\Sample)
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:36.429[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mcom.example.SampleApplication           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:36.505[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@10b48321: startup date [Wed Apr 13 19:56:36 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:37.313[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory    [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.100[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.118[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service Tomcat
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.120[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36morg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.32
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.280[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.280[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.web.context.ContextLoader           [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1779 ms
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.677[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.682[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.683[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.683[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:38.683[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[ost-startStop-1][0;39m [36mo.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.030[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@10b48321: startup date [Wed Apr 13 19:56:36 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.107[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/get]}" onto java.lang.String com.example.SampleApplication.get()
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.110[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.111[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.142[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.142[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.193[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.322[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter       [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.383[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol     [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SampleApplication.main(SampleApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]

[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.385[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:239) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:194) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SampleApplication.main(SampleApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:993) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:765) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:473) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:986) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar:8.0.32]
    ... 14 common frames omitted

[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.395[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Stopping service Tomcat
[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.406[0;39m [31mERROR[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.boot.SpringApplication              [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application startup failed

org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:293) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.SampleApplication.main(SampleApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar:1.3.3.RELEASE]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

[2m2016-04-13 19:56:39.409[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m4756[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36m.b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/E:/WS/Sample/target/classes/, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.1.5/logback-classic-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.1.5/logback-core-1.1.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.16/slf4j-api-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/1.7.16/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.16/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j/1.7.16/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.16/snakeyaml-1.16.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-logging-juli/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.0.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.32.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-validation/1.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.3.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/hibernate-validator/5.2.4.Final/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.0.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.1.0/classmate-1.1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.6.5/jackson-databind-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.6.5/jackson-annotations-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.6.5/jackson-core-2.6.5.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-web-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-aop-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/aopalliance/aopalliance/1.0/aopalliance-1.0.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-expression-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar, file:/C:/Users/kasi/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.2.5.RELEASE/spring-core-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar]
```

I am new to spring boot ,so i didn't get any idea to solve this.Please suggest me how to solve it?

May i know the problem of this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: seems you're trying to start the same application twice

Comment: Even i stop the server and run again this time also getting same issue.@SashaSalauyou

Comment: then, something else is listening port 8080. You may change the port which your application servlet is going to listen, e. g. in `server.xml` file.

Answer (score 18):

```
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
```

means that the port of your server (8080) is already in use. Make sure that your webserver is not running anymore from any previous starts.

Also check if there is any other application running on that port. Try to open http://localhost:8080/ to get a hint what's running there.

Comment: What can i do for the same? @f1sh

Comment: How i can stop that one? @f1sh

Comment: I have no idea what processes are running on your machine. One of them is already listening on port 8080, which prevents the startup of your tomcat.

Comment: In case you started it from eclipse, go to "Window" -> "Show Window" -> Debug. There you will find a list of all things started by eclipse, maybe one of them is still running. You can terminate it there.

Comment: I am using STS tool.@f1sh

Answer (score 13):

goto task manager -> processes and end Java(TM) Platform SE binary processes (this will stop tomcat) and run your spring boot application again.

Comment: This approach Worked!

Comment: Worked for me too. Awesome!

Answer (score 6):

[image]

Before running your Spring Boot App, click the red 'stop' button as shown above to first stop the server from running so that the port can be re-used. Then run your Spring Boot App.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks , it helped me

Comment: Thanks, it helped me too. Red button always works! Gosh, I wish they told me movie scenes are for real!!

Answer (score 6):

Faced the same issue. You could actually override tomcat port by just including application.properties under src/main/resources

application.properties file may look like

```
server.port = 8443
#below lines for SSL
#server.ssl.key-store = classpath:sample.jks
#server.ssl.key-store-password = secret
#server.ssl.key-password = password
```

Regards,

Srinidhi

Comment: Thanks,  this info helps how to run multiple spring boot microservices in different ports

Answer (score 4):

Follow steps to kill process on port

1] In command line interface

```
netstat -aon | find /i "listening"
```

2] Find port 8080
   Ctrl+F and Enter 8080 (Port number of a process you want to kill)

3] Kill it's associated process id.

Taskkill /PID ProcessNumber /F

```
Taskkill /PID 3440 /F
```

and rerun program

References : [List Processes](http://netstat%20-aon%20%7C%20find%20/i), [Kill a Process](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/shortcuts-to-kill-non-responding-appilcations-in-windows-7)

Answer (score 2):

Run the command with the port used: example: `lsof -i : 8080(Port number)`

Now kill the process.  command -: `kill -9 <PID>` (example : `kill -9 8080`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is already service using this port so you can find this service and stop it or you can change your application to listen to another port through

```
server.port=8081 # for example
```

In `application.properties` file

Answer (score 1):

Spring Boot uses port 8080 as the default port for the Inbuilt Apache Tomcat container. We can override it in many ways. One such way it to do it programmatically, given below.

Create this component. And compile and run your app. Change Port as per requirement.

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {
    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.setPort(8085);
        // Use port of your choice that is available
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run 2 instances of the same app, first check that the port configuration for both is different, then make sure the plugin you are using to run it is not checking for changes in the files and reloading your first instance, because what could be happening is that when you change your port for your second instance, the plugin is already relaunching the first one using this port, so when you run your second instance, port is already busy.

Answer (score 1):

Solved!  I have also faced this problem. it having many causes two instance running on same port. and also check the **attributes of Expression language** in jsp matches with **controller model attributes**. also check the Request Mapping proper or not.
 in my case missing only '/' symbol that's why it 
throws this error.

Answer (score 0):

Check the running processing using the below command.
****netstat -ano | findstr :****

If any results found in the below command then kill the processes using the below command.

**taskkill /PID  /F**
*Note: /F is used to force the kill process*

Answer (score 0):

Today I got same error and yesterday everything was ok.

The issue was I had this code lines in file ***resources\application.properties***:

```
server.address=10.202.133.23
server.port=8080
```

and the IP had changed. So, I realized in ipconfig (cmd) a new a IP becuasse of DHCP service. I changed server.address:

```
server.address=10.202.133.**24**
server.port=8080
```

and VOILA!